# PHP foreach with array nesting

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an application using PHP CodeIgniter's Cart library. And I need this output, to send info to google analytics:

```
$itemsga = array(
array('sku'=>'SDFSDF', 'name'=>'Shoes', 'category'=>'Footwear', 'price'=>'100', 'quantity'=>'1'),
array('sku'=>'123DSW', 'name'=>'Sandles', 'category'=>'Footwear', 'price'=>'87', 'quantity'=>'1'),
array('sku'=>'UHDF93', 'name'=>'Socks', 'category'=>'Footwear', 'price'=>'5.99', 'quantity'=>'2')
);
```

To achieve that, I created this code:

```
$itemsga = array(
  foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $items){
    array(
    'sku'              => $items['id'],
    'name'             => $items['name'],
    'price'            => $items['price'],
    'quantity'         => $items['qty'],
    ),
  }//endforeach
);
```

For some reason I'm getting a white screen. No error displayed but my array is not being built.

I know this might be a stupid question, but I got stuck. Can someone help me?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to:-

```
$itemsga = array(); // define array variable
  foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $items){
    $itemsga[] = array(
    'sku'              => $items['id'],
    'name'             => $items['name'],
    'price'            => $items['price'],
    'quantity'         => $items['qty'],
    ); // done indexing and add complete array to each index.
  }//endforeach
```

Comment: Great to hear that. Please mark it as an answer. it will help others also. thanks.:):):)